# How do I get field labels of all fields with api names for a particular object (Eg: Profile)?

Tags: soap-api

How do I get field labels of all fields with api names for a particular object (Eg: Profile)? I can do this using apex but I'm looking to have all these values in excel or csv?

Comment: Have you checked AppExchange for apps like Field Dumper?  There is also Schema Lister at cloudtoolkit.co

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using a third party free app called "Easy Describe".